# Multi query and auto increment?

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I'm having some real trouble figuring out this problem. The problem is in my database.php where I do all my database queries. This new function I'm creating have a foreach loop where it adds to a multi query and when the loop is finished all the queries get executed. (The multi query works in my other functions)

The MySQL table has a primary key id column with auto_increment and when the query tries to INSERT INTO it returns with an error.

So I leave out the id in my query to simple let MySQL take care of it with the auto increment. This is very the trouble starts and the multi query wont execute and tells me there is an error. if I simply fill out the id with my own values its fine.

database.php looks something like this

```
    $event .= "INSERT INTO table_info VALUES ('$userid', '$round', '$event');";

    // Execute multi query
    if (!$this->connection->multi_query($event)) {
        echo "Multi query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }

    do {
        if ($res = $this->connection->store_result()) {
            var_dump($res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
            $res->free();
        }
    } while ($this->connection->more_results() && $this->connection->next_result());
    return;
```

The odd thing is when I add the $round where the auto_increment id should be it works.

```
    $event .= "INSERT INTO table_info VALUES ('$round', '$userid', '$round', '$event');";
```

It seems like a waste to load the table and get the latest id and then +1 just to fill it into the query.

- Thank you for your time

Comment: What are the errors? It looks like you might be open to SQL injections.

Comment: Let MySQL handle the id

Comment: chris85: the Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Strawberry: My thought was that if I dont fill in the id column MySQL would handle it?

Comment: @chris85 is right its opened to SQL injection so you have to fix your code and make it secure , last thing if you have Auto Increment filed why you inserting data into it ? it should be auto filled so when you try to Insert into the table the value for the increment field can be like this : `    $event .= "INSERT INTO table_info VALUES ('', '$round', '$event');";` try it and tell us what happens

Comment: I thought it was secure so how do I secure it towards SQL injection?

Comment: @Kingfox what you have done, while using prepared statement syntax, is not anything that would prevent SQL injection. You would need to use [`->prepare(`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and then add your PHP variables in another command. There is a LOT on Stack Overflow about how to rewrite your code to do this correctly

Comment: Ohh okay, I need the prepared statement. I was just baffled to hear you could tell it was open to MySQL injection by this small of code. but thank you all for pointing this out and I will read up on how to use the prepared statement. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$event .= "INSERT INTO table_info (`user_id_column_name`,`round_column_name`,`event_column_name`) VALUES ('$userid', '$round', '$event');";
```

You need to specify the columns if the no of values are less than total no of fields

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is as you are not inserting into every column on the table -  as you are correctly avoiding `race conditions` by letting MySQL handle this with the `auto_increment` column - you need to define on your insert which columns you are inserting into:

```
 INSERT INTO table_info (column names here separated by commas)
  VALUES ( '$userid', '$round', '$event');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify columns names and allow mysql to take care of AUTO_INCREMENT your id field you should send it with NULL value. See code below:

```
$event .= "INSERT INTO table_info VALUES (NULL, '$userid', '$round', '$event');";
```

Comment: I tried to set it to 0, NULL, DEFAULT but it still wouldn't accept the query